# Nebula Graph (nGQL) Cypher not returning values in jupyter

Tags: llama-index, nebula-graph

Trying to run a Nebula Graph Query Cypher from the excellent tutorial by Wenqi Glantz:
https://www.nebula-graph.io/posts/Knowledge-Graph-and-LlamaIndex

```cypher
%%ngql 
MATCH (p:`entity`)-[e:relationship]->(m:`entity`)
  WHERE p.`entity`.`name` == 'Philadelphia Phillies'
RETURN p, e, m;
```

Doing so returns no values for p,e,m.

Running the same request using plain text/sentences using the query engine returns an appropriate answer just fine.

Unsure why the ngql query cypher is failing to yield results. Thanks for your help.